# Manager in/at a private medical centre

Tags: prepositions

From a person's profile at a work-oriented website:

> 2006 till present: manager in Business Development Department **in**
>   a private medical centre in Moscow, Russia

Does the *in* preposition look good here? Or maybe the preposition *at* would fit more nicely?

> 2006 till present: manager in Business Development Department **at**
>   a private medical centre in Moscow, Russia

As an aside, wouldn't it be better to write "Business Development Department manager", omitting the first "in" construction?

P.S. Regarding the overlap with the existing "working for\in the XYZ company" question, it seems to me that my question differs somewhat, since a company is a thing less concrete and definite than a set of buildings comprising a medical centre. Yes, *for* works fine with *the XYZ company*, but let's translpant it in our scenario:

> 2006 till present: manager in Mopping Department **for** a corner cafe.